# What are benefits of running ELK stack on Docker over running it on VM

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm learning ELK stack. I wonder, why would people run it on Docker?
If I understand everything correctly, it would have to have some directory of a host OS mapped to be persistent over resets of the image.
Meanwhile, running just VL with installed docker would be persistent anyway.

Why should I use Docker to run ELK stack? In fact, should I use Docker or VM? Is the performance the only reason to choose Docker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good question that makes make think of my favorite xkcd comic:
https://xkcd.com/1988/

When running the Docker images you are getting installations prepared by the software creators. All you need to do is glue them together with your configuration. You don't need to learn all about how to install the apps, just run them.

With a `docker-compose` manifest (like [this one](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)) you can be up and running on an ELK stack on any Docker compatible system with a single, well documented command.

Elastic, the creators of ELK, also have a nice write up about running their software quickly and easily on Docker:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-full-stack-in-one-command